# Invoke methods in mule esb from c# (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mule, esb

I have class library (.dll file) with classes and methods (c#). How can i use this library in mule esb?
//i know about dotnet connector but dont want to use it. (want to create a service with mule standalone and dotnet connector is part of enterprace edition and i dont want to pay for that ;D)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java class to do just this. I recommend checking out jni4net here, they have examples: https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/wiki/Calling-C%23-in-Java